# Error: Login attribute is required using Sentry and Laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

Since today, my login controller (using Sentry) doesn't work anymore.
I already changed it 10203902 times but it keeps giving me the error: "a [login] attribute is required". For the past 2-3 weeks this controller worked fine.

LoginController

```
 <?php namespace Digitus\Auth\Controllers;

use Illuminate\View\Environment as View;
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Sentry;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector as Redirect;

class LoginController extends \Digitus\Base\Controllers\BController{

    public function __construct(Input $input, View $view, Sentry $sentry, Redirect $redirect){
        $this->input    = $input;
        $this->view     = $view;
        $this->sentry   = $sentry;
        $this->user     = $this->sentry->getUser();
        $this->redirect = $redirect;

        if($this->sentry->check()) {
            $user = $this->sentry->getUser();
        } else {
            $user = null;
        }
        $this->view->share('loggedUser', $user);
    }

    protected $input;
    protected $view;
    protected $sentry;
    protected $redirect;

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->view->make('user.login');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $user = $this->user->where('username', $this->input->get('email_or_username'))->orWhere('email', $this->input->get('email_or_username'))->first();
        $credentials = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email_or_username') ?: null,
            'password' => $this->input->get('password'),
        );
        try {
            $user = $this->sentry->authenticate($credentials, false);

            if($this->sentry->check())
            {
                return $this->redirect->to('admin');
            } else {
                return $this->redirect->to('');
            }
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            return $this->redirect->to('login')->withErrors(array('login'=> $e->getMessage()));
        }
    }

}
```

View

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')

<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">PLease Login</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login')) }}
            @if($errors->has('login'))
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                    {{ $errors->first('login', ':message') }}
                </div>
            @endif
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('email_or_username', 'Email Address or Username') }}
                {{ Form::email('email_or_username', '', array('class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Please enter your Email Address or Username to login', 'autofocus')) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
                {{ Form::password('password', array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Password')) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::submit('Login', array('class'=>'btn btn-success')) }}
                {{ HTML::link('/', 'Cancel', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger')) }}
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h2>Don't have an account?</h2>
                {{ HTML::link('register', 'Please register here', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-xs'))}}
            </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@stop
```

I've already asked many people for solutions or fixes etc. They all didn't work..

PS & FYI: I also published the Sentry config, and the login_attribute is email.
Any help or input would be great. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentry also uses the

```
protected static $loginAttribute = 'email';
```

To get the login data, check if you have made changes to it. Those are the lines that are giving you a hard time:

```
$loginName = $this->userProvider->getEmptyUser()->getLoginName();

$loginCredentialKey = (isset($credentials[$loginName])) ? $loginName : 'login';
```

Basically if `$loginAttribute` is not available it will use 'login' as the credential key. So you can also test to give what it wants:

```
$credentials = array(
    'email' => Input::get('email_or_username') ?: null,
    'login' => Input::get('email_or_username') ?: null,
    'password' => $this->input->get('password'),
);
```

Unfortunately, you cannot have two different fields to login your user, so if you need this you'll have to do your check manually, so you probably will be able to do something like:

```
public function login()
{
    $user = $this->sentry->getUserProvider()->getEmptyUser();

    $user = $user->where('email', $this->input->get('email_or_username'))
                        ->orWhere('username', $this->input->get('email_or_username'))
                        ->first();

    try 
    {
        if ($user && Hash::check($this->input->get('password'), $user->password)) /// here you check if a user was found
        {
            $this->sentry->login($user, false); /// remember = false /// here is the login happening in case of true
        }
        else
        {
            // user not found or wrong password
        }
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        return $this->redirect->to('login')->withErrors(array('login'=> $e->getMessage()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you look at that.. It works.. apparently i changed the protected statis $loginAttribute to username..  Thanks for that Antonio, but where were you this morning? ;) :p

Comment: BTW, as you may have seen, i want users to be able to login using their username or email address. As i've been told, the way i did it was wrong. So.. I'd like to kindly ask you if you would know anything about this?

Comment: Okay, just edited. I don't think you can use both fields to login with sentry, so you might need to do it manually, but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Ok thanks Antonio! I'll try this out when i'm back! Anyways thanks, i appreciate your help

Comment: I'm using your example like this now: http://laravel.io/bin/OlQK

But it doesn't seem to work. I'm affraid i did something wrong. Do you know what it could be?

Comment: I mean, when i enter i.e. the username of a user, it still says: A user could not be found with a login value of [jeroenheki]. I still have to login using the email address.

Comment: You were still using sentry to authenticate, you really have to do it manually, check this code: http://laravel.io/bin/Pa55

Comment: Well, i tried it. Removed the line, but now it's not really doing anything though.. I guess its still going wrong somewhere..  It catches the exception, but doesnt do the rule that is defined there. 

Btw: it isn't working for neither username or email.

Comment: There was indeed a small problem with that code, when usin `->where()...->first()` I was not assigning the found user value to `$user`. Just edited my question to post new full login() method. I tested this one in my end and it worked.